# Add spaces in string but not between quotes

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, tokenize

I have this string:

```
string myString = "do Output.printString(\"Do you want to Hit (h) or Stand (s)?\");";
```

My string as plain text:

> do Output.printString("Do you want to Hit (h) or Stand (s)?");

I want to make it:

> do Output . printString ("Do@you@want@to Hit@(h)@or@Stand@(s)?");

The idea is that there is a space between each word but if there is a string within apostrophes I want it to be **WITHOUT SPACE** and after this function I can do:

```
s.Split(' ');
```

and get the string in one string.

What I did is:

```
 public static string PrepareForSplit(this string s)
    {
        string ret = "";
        if (s.Contains("\""))
        {
            bool equalsAppear = false;
            foreach (var nextChar in s)
            {
                char charToConcat;
                if (nextChar == '"')
                {
                   equalsAppear= equalsAppear == true ? false : true;
                }

                if (nextChar == ' ' && equalsAppear)
                {

                    charToConcat = '@';

                }
                else
                {
                    charToConcat = nextChar;
                }
                ret += charToConcat;
            }

        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ret))
            ret = s;
        string[] symbols = {"{", "}", "(", ")", "[", "]", ".",
    ",", ";", "+", "-", "*", "/", "&", "|", "<", ">", "=", "~","#"};

        foreach(var symbol in symbols)
        if(ret.Contains(symbol))
        {
            if (!ret.Contains('"') || !((symbol=="-") || symbol==","))
            {
                ret = ret.Replace(symbol, " " + symbol + " ");
            }
        }
        if(ret.Contains("\t"))
        {
            ret = Regex.Replace(ret, @"\t", " ");
        }

        return ret;

    }
```

My problem is that in the end of this function I get this string:

> do Output . printString ( "Do@you@want@to@Hit@ ( h ) @or@Stand@ ( s ) ?" )  ;

As you can see in the string that suppose to be without spacing I have spaces and then my program not behave as it should. Someone please help!

Comment: You can do that with regex.

Comment: How? can you write the regex?

Comment: How does `printString` print a quote?

Comment: printstring is part of my string I will update the question that it will be more clear...

Comment: When you say "apostrophes" (`'`), do you mean "parentheses" (`()`)?

Comment: no I mean this token: " between the two " in the middle of the string I dont want that will be spaces...

Comment: I cannot understand your question; this is an apostrophe `'` and there are none in your example string. Do you mean these: `"`? Those are quotes, not apostrophes. You say you want a result without spaces, yet there is a space in your example of what you want between `to` and `Hit`. We also need to know how you would print a quote (one of these -> `"`) in your `printString`.

Comment: I edited the title I mean to " and @Olivier solve my issue

Comment: I think this is way to much code to solve your string manipulation problem. The more code, the more bugs.

Comment: If you have better way I would be glad if you write it as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to split the whole string at the apostrophes. This will make it much easier to differentiate between parts that are within apostrophes and the others.

```
string[] parts = s.Split('"');
```

Now you have:

```
part[0] ==> "do Output . printString ("
part[1] ==> "Do@you@want@to Hit@(h)@or@Stand@(s)?"
part[2] ==> ");"
```

I.e., the even indexes in `part[]` are outside the apostrophes, the odd indexes are within.

```
// Treat the parts not between apostrophes:
for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i += 2) {
    part[i] = InsertSpacesBetweenWords(part[i]); 
}

string result = String.Join("\"", part);
```

---

By the way: In your example, you can simplify

```
equalsAppear = equalsAppear == true ? false : true;
```

to

```
equalsAppear = !equalsAppear;
```

by using the logical NOT operator `!`.

Comment: Very good answer this is why I love stack overflow thank you! this solve my problem and saves me lot of hours!

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regular expression to extract your string.

You probably enter the starting string like this:

```
string source = "do Output.printString(\"Do you want to Hit (h) or Stand (s)?\");";
```

Try this regular expression:

```
\("([^\"]+)
```

The group between round brackets (i.e. the capturing group) is what you're looking for.

Edit: use it like this (based on http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // First we see the input string.
        string source = "do Output.printString(\"Do you want to Hit (h) or Stand (s)?\");";

        // Here we call Regex.Match.
        Match match = Regex.Match(source, "\\(\"([^\"]+)");

        // Here we check the Match instance.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
            string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
            Console.WriteLine("result: "+ key);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nothing found");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Edit2: now it works :-)

Comment: can you write it more clear? I can't understand how to use it